# How to return T, when I know class which is hidden behind it?

Tags: c#, reflection, types, abstract, leaky-abstraction

I know that T is `List<string>` (or `List<MyClass>`). How should look reflection or something that allow me to return this List of string?

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string response)
{
    //just example
    string[] words = response.Split(' ');
    List<string> wordsList = words.ToList();
    //?
    return wordsList;
}
```

Background: Deserialize method is used to parse html data. It is something like own myJson.myDeserialize method used in Website, which does not have API.

Comment: If you need to return `List<string>` why not mark the return type as `List<string>`?

Comment: Well what would you want the contents of the list to be if `T` is `List<MyClass>`?

Comment: this question has the tag *abstraction*, but I think it should be tagged *leaky abstraction*

Comment: Deserialize method is used to parse html data. It is something like own myJson.myDeserialize method used in Website, which does not have API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an awkward trick for achieving this: You need to first cast your instance to `object`.

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string response)
{
    string[] words = response.Split(' ');
    List<string> wordsList = words.ToList();

    return (T)(object)wordsList;
}
```

This assumes that your caller specifies `List<string>` as the generic type.

```
var x = Deserialize<List<string>>("hello world");    // gives "hello", "world"
var y = Deserialize<int>("hello world");             // throws InvalidCastException
```